# HTML5 download attribute working but redirecting to url

Tags: html

HTML5 download attribute with url working for me but it is redirecting me to new page.
Here is my code -

```
exportToPdf: function(e) {
 var link = document.createElement('a');
 link.href = 'https://filegenerator.com/download?guid=d85c9ca87a374df1a81b1503406ebead';
 link.download = "Report";
 link.click();
}
```

HTML code-

```
 <a id="exportToPdf">Export to PDF</a>
```

[image]

Also tried doing this way -

```
<a download="" href="https://filegenerator.com/download?guid=d85c9ca87a374df1a81b1503406ebead" id="exportToPdf">Export to PDF</a>
```

But not working.
Please suggest any other way of doing this.

Comment: `This attribute only works for same-origin URLs.` That asumes that your document has the same domain as the download file url. Is this the problem? See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Comment: Thanks for that. Is there any other way to achieve what i want?

Comment: @shahistainamdar, you can try these answers [Chrome 65 blocks cross-origin <a download>. Client-side workaround to force download?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49474775/14928633)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a download="" href="https://filegenerator.com/download?guid=d85c9ca87a374df1a81b1503406ebead" id="exportToPdf">Export to PDF</a>
```

This is working completely fine as I had written a code for click of anchor and was redirecting it to new page using window.open(url).
Because of that it was redirecting.