# HTML5 download attribute not working when download external PDF file on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

The code is very simple:

```
<a download href="http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf">Download</a>
```

I expect it to save the pdf file but it always open the file on the browser.

It works with other file type, just have problem with PDF file.

Comment: I believe this is something configurable in the browser side. You can choose weather to download or visualize a PDF

Comment: Can you add more context? What browser/platform? Are you stopping it via JS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PDF file not downloading with HTML5 download attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51861852/pdf-file-not-downloading-with-html5-download-attribute)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes):

> This attribute only works for same-origin URLs.

Presumably, the other file types, where you see it "working", are ones where the default behaviour is to download the file.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you're right. Anyway, I worked around by fetch the blob data and build the file url locally to download.

Answer (score 4):

If the URL that you're trying to fetch has an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, you can work around this by using `fetch` and blobs:

```js
function forceDownload(blob, filename) {
  // Create an invisible anchor element
  const anchor = document.createElement('a');
  anchor.style.display = 'none';
  anchor.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  anchor.setAttribute('download', filename);
  document.body.appendChild(anchor);

  // Trigger the download by simulating click
  anchor.click();

  // Clean up
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(anchor.href);
  document.body.removeChild(anchor);
}

function downloadResource(url, filename) {
  fetch(url, {
    headers: new Headers({
      Origin: window.location.origin,
    }),
    mode: 'cors',
  })
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => forceDownload(blob, filename))
    .catch(e => console.error(e));
}

downloadResource('https://memegen.link/xy/fetch/all_the_things.jpg?watermark=none');
```

This has a few limitations:

- the file size limit of blobs is about 500MB
- some websites will not allow for cross-origin requests, leading to errors like this one below

> Failed to load https://example.com/example.jpg: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Ref 1: [Leeroy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5266640/leeroy) in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49500465/1268612

Ref 2: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-download

Full explanation: https://blog.logrocket.com/programmatic-file-downloads-in-the-browser-9a5186298d5c/

Comment: this solution worked for me. tks very much. one small detail: i didn't need the filename parse from the url. i set the download attribute without the filename value and the name was inferred automatically.

Comment: Great, thanks for the feedback and improvement @JoãoMelo! I've removed this part of the code.