# PDF file not downloading with HTML5 download attribute

Tags: html, pdf, download, anchor

I have a download attribute on two different anchor tags. One is for an Excel file and one for PDF. The Excel file downloads. The PDF opens in new tab instead. Why is this happening? Code below:

```
        <div class="col-2 center">
            <a download href="files/excel-sample.xlsx">
                <img src="img/excel-logo.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 center">
            <a download href="files/pdf-sample.pdf">
                <img src="img/pdf-logo.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? The download attribute is currently not supported by IE or Safari on iOS as a heads up

Comment: @bbestul I am in Chrome on a microsoft machine.

Comment: Perfect - the download attribute should work in most updated versions of Chrome so you should be good from that angle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Download Basics**

So essentially what is happening is that when you link to a file URL, the browser opens that URL and if it has accessibility to display the content, it almost always will. Some most common examples of this are image files (.png, .jpg, etc...). However, if the browser can't read the file type (.zip) then it will almost always download the content. A great way to force the browser to download the file is by adding the `download` attribute in the `<a>` tag.

PDFs are readable and accessible by most modern browsers so by default, the browser is set to open the file instead of download it. Because of this accessibility, most modern browsers have introduced settings that allow users to decide on a machine by machine basis whether or not a PDF (or any other readable file) should open in another window or download by default. In many cases, even with the `download` attribute, the browser can still decide for itself how to handle the file.

**Possible Solutions**

**1** - If you are just trying to achieve the download functionality on your browser only (which it looks like you aren't but I thought I should include anyway), you can open chrome, go to Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Content Settings -> PDF Documents -> Toggle on Download

**2** - You can compress and zip the file so the browser is forced to download the file.

**3** - If you have root server access to your site and it is using Apache, you can add the following to your .htaccess

```
ForceType application/octet-stream
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
```

If you are using an NGINX web server, you can add the following redirect

```
location ~* (.*\.pdf) {
types { application/octet-stream .pdf; }
default_type application/octet-stream;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

So the solution is:

```
<a href="pdf-sample"  download="pdf-samle.pdf">
```

Note that "href" has a value without the .pdf reduction, but "download" has a value with the .pdf reduction. Remember you also have to remove the .pdf reduction from the targeted file. As it seems the browser treats the downloaded file as a non pdf file and therefore is not opening it by default.

Comment: Why am I getting a mins point for that answer. If you want I can clarify my answer. But the presented solution is solving the problem and is working perfectly - the pdf does not open, but instead gets downloaded!

Answer (score -6):

you cannot use `<a download href="files/pdf-sample.pdf">`
but you can use `<a href="files/pdf-sample.pdf">` for preview your file

Comment: they are asking how to install you are talking about preview.