# link to download the file doesn't work but opens the file (html5)

Tags: html, download

I think there is nothing wrong. I have watched lots of videos and nearly all of them were the same syntax. Maybe something with javascript?!

```
<a href="file.pdf" download>download</a>
```

I've tried also this but didn't work. Same result

```
<a href="file.pdf" download="fileName">download</a>
```

Comment: Where is the file you are trying to download located? Also, keep in mind where the html file is and where the file to be downloaded is relative to it. Also, are you hosting this anywhere or is this on your local machine?

Comment: it is local and there is no backend. the file and my HTML are in the same directory.

Comment: Which browser? @johnalcantara

Comment: chrome. but I tried almost all (IE, Microsoft Edge, ...)

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of [pdf-file-not-downloading-with-html5-download-attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51861852/pdf-file-not-downloading-with-html5-download-attribute). Please check the detailed answer there.

Comment: yeah, I found the answer. thank you Rhythm

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solutions

1 - If you are just trying to achieve the download functionality on your browser only (which it looks like you aren't but I thought I should include anyway), you can open chrome, go to Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Content Settings -> PDF Documents -> Toggle on Download

2 - You can compress and zip the file so the browser is forced to download the file.