# <a> download attribute not working anymore

Tags: html, cross-domain

I used to use this code to download resources:

```
<a href='http://example.com' download> Download </a>
```

Where example.com is another website (cross origin).

But this is not working now , I tried Chrome - Opera - Mozilla and even Internet Explorer , But it's not working.

Comment: Certain browsers disallow cross domain download attributes in a links. You've already tried a bunch, so your best bet would be to try using a direct file (such as site.com/index.php, or site.com/file.zip) to test it out. You should also make sure to check the console log and ensure there is nothing overriding the default behavior (JS for example in footer).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome 65 blocks cross-origin <a download>. Client-side workaround to force download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474775/chrome-65-blocks-cross-origin-a-download-client-side-workaround-to-force-down)

Answer (score 11):

See https://caniuse.com/#search=download ("Known Issues" Tab) where it says:

> Firefox only supports same-origin download links.
>
> Chrome 65 and above only supports same-origin download links.

IE does not support the download-attribute at all

Comment: http only & same-origin

Answer (score -1):

All major browsers have implemented this as a security guard for the user. 
In addition it is stated in the [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#as-a-download)
([link](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4969697975992320) to chrome feature)