# Javascript Bookmarklet - Download Images

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, imagedownload

**Edit:** Thanks to @Dogoku, I was able to find a solution ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474775/chrome-65-blocks-cross-origin-a-download-client-side-workaround-to-force-down)). It turns out that Chrome doesn't allow/handle the download attribute anymore, so we have to force a workaround.

---

I'm trying to create a javascript bookmarklet that downloads images (code shown below). It's accessing the url correctly, but instead of downloading the image it just opens the image in a new tab.

Please help!

```
r.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    r.href = h;
    r.download = c;
}, false);

document.body.appendChild(r), r.click(), document.body.removeChild(r);
```

the variable r is created using document.createElement("a") which creates an element like so:

```
<a href="url" download="filename"></a>
```

Before, when using a bookmarklet you could basically just "click" on the image and it would download.

Comment: what is c that is set to the download property? can you try setting a string (filename)?

Comment: c is the filename :) The image is part of a set that is dynamically grabbed and looped through. Then, the image url is parsed to get the file name.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. is the first image of the loop downloading correctly, but failing for others? perhaps trying putting a delay between the downloads?

Comment: I can log out the entire process and it's looping through all of them - so nothing is failing; however, instead of downloading the image it's opening it (all of them) in a new tab and doing nothing.

Comment: could this be related (if img urls are considered cross origin) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474775/chrome-65-blocks-cross-origin-a-download-client-side-workaround-to-force-down?

Comment: @Dogoku I'm looking into that! It would make a lot of sense if that's the issue I'm running into