# <a> tag download attribute not working for mobile

Tags: android, html, iphone, download, anchor

I have this anchor tag as below:

```
<a className="badge-link" href="./download/myapp-v1.1.0.apk" download="myapp-v1.1.0.apk">
   <img src="img/download-apk.png" alt=""/>
</a>
```

Just want to clarify that the apk file & website is hosted at a server and I'm downloading the file from there.

The download works on PC but on mobile it gets stuck at downloading status forever.

It doesn't show download progress at all.

I've tried closing the download manager & clearing its cache for android but I still get the same result.

How do I make this download work on android/iphone?
Or is there any other alternatives?

Comment: which browser you are using in phone and PC?

Comment: the latest browser of chrome and firefox have removed the cross-origin downloads.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474775/chrome-65-blocks-cross-origin-a-download-client-side-workaround-to-force-down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue seems to be with the path u specified in the href. Try giving absolete path like

> "http://somedomain.com/somefolder/somefile"

```
    <a className="badge-link" onclick="startDownload('http://somedomain.com/somefolder/somefile')" download="myapp-v1.1.0.apk"> <img src="img/download-apk.png" alt=""/> </a>

//Js to open in the same tab
<script>function startDownload(url) { window.location.href = url; }
</script>
```

On the HTTP Response where you are returning the file, ensure the content disposition header looks like:

> Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.extesion;

Check this for more about content [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition)-disposition

Just to test give some third party link first later try with yours

Comment: just tested, it ends up opening the file in the browser instead

Comment: Are you testing it in iphone or on Android

Comment: testing at android

Comment: Adding `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.extesion;` worked

Answer (score 0):

I think in your pc you have that apk file on the project folder, but in your mobile and also in your project folder that apk file is missing.
And also you can try this code

```
<a className="badge-link" href="download/myapp-v1.1.0.apk" download>
    <img src="img/download-apk.png" alt=""/>
</a>
```

Comment: I'm downloading from the server, not from local

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a className="badge-link" href="http://somedomain.com/download/myapp-v1.1.0.apk" download="myapp-v1.1.0.apk"> 
  <img src="img/download-apk.png" alt=""/> 
</a>
```

Comment: It ends up viewing the file in the browser

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because when you're testing on PC, you have the apk inside your project directory.
But you don't have it on mobile.

Comment: I'm downloading from a server, the file exists there. Download on other PC works fine, except mobile