# How do I make clicking a link download an image?

Tags: html

I've been looking around, and I find something that for some reason works for some links, but when I try to download my image it just opens the page with the image

```
<a href="https://i.imgur.com/KBUpwNd.jpg" download="V2Map">Download</a>
```

I expect this to download the imgur image I linked, but it just opens the link instead, any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome 65 blocks cross-origin <a download>. Client-side workaround to force download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474775/chrome-65-blocks-cross-origin-a-download-client-side-workaround-to-force-down)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just made a quick test and it seems like that origin domain matters in this case.

The download attribute works fine if [the image is on the same domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download). Otherwise it opens the link.

> - This attribute only works for same-origin URLs.
> - Although HTTP(s) URLs need to be in the same-origin, blob: URLs and data: URLs are allowed so that content generated by JavaScript, such as pictures created in an image-editor Web app, can be downloaded.
> - If the HTTP header Content-Disposition: gives a different filename than this attribute, the HTTP header takes priority over this attribute.
> - If Content-Disposition: is set to inline, Firefox prioritizes Content-Disposition, like the filename case, while Chrome prioritizes the download attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The `download` attribute only works for same origin URLS. 
You could either write a server side script.

**OR**
Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474775/chrome-65-blocks-cross-origin-a-download-client-side-workaround-to-force-down?noredirect=1&lq=1) discussion for a quick workaround.

Simply insert your URL into the `downloadResource()` like so: `downloadResource('https://i.imgur.com/KBUpwNd.jpg');` Wrap in `script` tags and run on your browser.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) description of the `download` attribute:

> This attribute only works for same-origin URLs.

So it won't work with a URL that points to a different domain than your own, such as `i.imgur.com`.

You can use a proxy script on your own server, something like:

```
<a href="/image_download.php?url=https://i.imgur.com/KBUpwNd.jpg" download="V2Map">Download</a>
```

Then write the `image_download.php` script that does:

```
readfile($_GET['url']);
```

You should of course have validation checks in the script so that it doesn't get abused as a general-purpose proxy by third parties. Google "php proxy" and you'll find some pre-written scripts.

Comment: When I try to download it says "Failed - No file"

Comment: Did you write the proxy script?