# How to download/save file of different extensions of different origin in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I use ReactJS and need to download the file. The catch is I CAN'T use

```
     <a href={url} download={filename}></a>
```

Because the URL is coming from S3 bucket which is of different origin according to the documentation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

I tried this but didn't work

```
        import React from 'react';
        import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
        import IconDownload from '@material-ui/icons/CloudDownloadTwoTone';

        const styles = theme => ({
          root: { 
          },
        });

        class AttachmentViewer extends React.PureComponent {
          static propTypes = {
            open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
            filename: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            filePath: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
          };

          render() {
            const { filePath, filename } = this.props;
            return (
              <div>
                <a href={`${filePath}`} download={filename}>
                  <IconDownload />
                </a>
              </div>
            );
          }
        }

        export default withStyles(styles)(AttachmentViewer);
```

The above code is just opening the file once again.

I am getting the file path correctly as a prop. But it has a different origin.

Any idea how to download the file?

Comment: Have you tried setting up a proxy to get around CORS?  A common practice to get around CORS is to setup a node express backend to serve up data from different origins.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome 65 blocks cross-origin <a download>. Client-side workaround to force download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474775/chrome-65-blocks-cross-origin-a-download-client-side-workaround-to-force-down)

Comment: @JakeLuby, Unfortunatly I am not allowed to.

Comment: @Sheepy , had a look but I don't want to create elements directly in DOM, coz we are using ReactJS. There must be some other way which doesn't touch the actual DOM