# html download attribute redirects to url instead of downloading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Noob webdeveloper here.

I'm trying to download an image from an url on click. But when I use the image url as my href it just redirects to that url instead of downloading. Of course I am using the download attribute. I have tried my own code and also mulitple code blocks from other people. But all of them just redirect. I am using google chrome.

My code:

```
<a href = "https://autoooo.nl/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/F5144B9C-2B27-4070-828E-2361EBD702EF-400x400.jpeg" download="car" id="downloadQRCodeButtonHref">
   <p>download</p>
</a>
```

Code I used from [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408146/href-image-link-download-on-click) 1(accepted answer):

```
<a download="custom-filename.jpg" href="/path/to/image" title="ImageName">
   <img alt="ImageName" src="/path/to/image">
</a>
```

Code I used from [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408146/href-image-link-download-on-click) 2:

```
 <p> Click the image ! You can download! </p>
<?php
$image =  basename("http://localhost/sc/img/logo.png"); // you can here put the image path dynamically 
//echo $image;
?>
<a download="<?php echo $image; ?>" href="http://localhost/sc/img/logo.png" title="Logo title">
    <img alt="logo" src="http://localhost/sc/img/logo.png">
</a>
```

Some help will be appreciated. I might just be a big dum dum and overlook something extremely obvious.

Comment: is this your answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/724449/12232340 ?

Comment: This downloads an image from an already existing php page with the image on it. I want to download an image from an url. But it might come in handy. Thanks.

Comment: Related question [Chrome 65 blocks cross-origin <a download>. Client-side workaround to force download?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49474775/14928633)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is because you're using a cross-domain URL. From the documentation for the [`download` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download):

> `download` only works for same-origin URLs, or the `blob:` and `data:` schemes.

To fix this you need to host the image on the same domain as the parent site.