# html 'download' attribute opens up a new page instead of downloading

Tags: html, download, anchor, imagedownload

I'm trying to make a download button for an image using the following code:

```html
<a href="https://media.npr.org/assets/img/2017/09/14/gettyimages-10141026_slide-67be9fc1bca330b26debade87690b5e84286614d-s800-c85.jpg" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" target="_blank" download>Download</a>
```

However, when the button is clicked, it redirects to a page with the image on it instead of downloading the image. I've searched for solution for this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60522840/html-download-attribute-redirects-to-url-instead-of-downloading). The answer said that it's probably because I'm using a cross-domain URL, and to fix this I need to host the image on the same domain as the parent site. But I don't know what the answer means. Can someone help me fix this problem? Appreciate your help!

By the way, I'm using Google Chrome as the browser.

Comment: Save the image into your folders and then use the new file location to download from.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've changed my code as the following: 
<a href="./pic/3Bunnies.jpg" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" target="_blank" download="3Bunnies.jpg">Download</a>
However, it still doesn't work. =(

Comment: Don't think you need download="3Bunnies.jpg" just download. Also I don't think you need the . infront of /pic .

Comment: I've changed it. <a href="./pic/3Bunnies.jpg" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" target="_blank" download>Download</a> Still doesn't work. I'm using Google Chrome by the way.

Comment: use /pic/3Bunnies.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to caniuse report:

> Chrome 65 and above only supports same-origin download links. 
> Firefox only supports same-origin download links

The same-origin means that you have to actually download the image or whatever to your local computer if you're developing with your own computer and use `<a href="./pic/[Pic_Name].[Pic_Ext]" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" target="_blank" download>Download</a>`

And if you are developing with localhost, just omit the . before the /pic. Same for a remote server.

Also, if you're using an outdated version of the browser, the download attribute never works. Check [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=Download) for more...