# Download attribute ignored on iOS Chrome/Firefox etc

Tags: html, ios, google-chrome

The download attribute seems to be ignored in **non Safari** browsers on iOS. This minimalistic `<a download>` example does not trigger download prompt but opens the link in the browser window:

https://tutsplus.github.io/download-attribute/index.html

It works as expected on Chrome / Firefox desktop and Android. It also works on iOS Safari.

This is not a [cross domain issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474775/chrome-65-blocks-cross-origin-a-download-client-side-workaround-to-force-down). Plenty of similar issues here on SO but they mostly deal with slightly different cases. Also I cannot fix this on the server with `content-disposition` header (if that was going to help anyway).

Is there maybe something in iOS that prevents non-safari browsers triggering the download dialog?

What's the solution here?